# Maximo anywhere error when deploying adapter on worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I need to use maximo anywhere so i have installed `worklight server` and `worklight studio`. from worklight studio when trying to deploy adapter on `worklight` i got this error in console :

```
Adapter deployment failed
Not Found; Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri : /console/api/adapters/upload
```

What can be the cause of this problem? Can you help me please?

Comment: May I know the procedure you have followed to deploy adapter?

Comment: Also mention your Worklight version. Additionally mention explicitly whether or not this is an attempt to create an adapter in Studio and then deploy it via Worklight Console, located in a different application server that Worklight Server is deployed to. Please don't spare in any details.

Comment: I'm usin worklight server 5.0.6

Comment: I did these steps :   1. Install Maximo anywhere              2. Install Worlight (Server and studio). worklight was installed in Web Sphere by installetor.  

3. build gen and dist.  
When i did build gen a worklight project was generated (MaximoAnywhereProject ).
  To deploy adapter i did the following :                                                                                                                   Expand MaximoAnywhereProject - > Expand adapters - > Right click on 'OSLCGenericAdapter'  - > Choose 'Run As' - > 'Deploy Worklight Adapter'

Comment: Does it *always* happen? Can you try re-installing Studio?

Comment: @IdanAdar yes always. ok i will try

Comment: @IdanAdar it's always the same problem even when reinstalling worklight studio.

Comment: @developer31, is this issue still valid?

Answer (score 0):

The current suggestion is to upgrade the Studio installation to either the latest 5.0.6.2 iFix level, or to Worklight 6.0, as Worklight 5.0.6 is no longer a supported product level.